# margin-bottom with overflow hidden

Tags: html, css

In the following code:

```
<a href="*">
    <h3>My really really long header</h3>
    <img src="thumbnail.png" width="150" height="100" />
</a>
```

The `h3` overflows its size. If I set the overflow to hidden, an extra margin is added to the bottom of the `h3`. If I change the header to short one, the extra bottom margin does not appear.

After searching SO I found something about collapsing margins. But the point is there is no margin applied to `img` nor to `h3`.

Here is the CSS:

```
h3 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #0f0;
}

a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 160px;
    height: auto;
}

img {
    background-color: #00f;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sz9yhv79/)

If I set the `font-size` of tag `a` to zero, the extra margin doesn't show up.

**Question**: Is there a proper way (not setting `font-size: 0`) to solve this issue?

Comment: margin-top:-4px; - probably that's not what you want but it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your `h3` set to `inline-block`. By default, `inline-block` respects `line-height` and `font-size`. Change your `h3` to display block.

css:

```
h3 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #0f0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: But why does this problem only show up when overflow is hidden? If it's `inline-block` the whole time, why doesn't this problem show up even without `overflow:hidden` ?

Comment: Because changing overflow to anything but visible, changes the [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context). If you use dev tools to view the computed style, you'll notice that once you add the `overflow: hidden` to an element with `inline-block` set as the display, it'll compute at `display: block`. [more information on overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `display: inline-block` from the `h3`, or add `vertical-align:bottom`.

That you are making the `h3` an `inline-block` element is causing this, because as such it gets laid out in the line box in a way that leaves space for the descenders of characters of (potential) text content on that same line.